# How is pricing calculated for Azure Container Instance with restart policy Always

Tags: azure, azure-container-instances

I have a Linux nodejs express webapp container deployed to Azure Container Instances with the restart policy set to Always.

How will the pricing be calculated for this?

Is it per http request or for 24/7 using the memory/cpu duration described at [Azure Container Instances Pricing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/container-instances/)?

This is a low volume webapp for internal usage only during work hours and locked down with Azure AD openid connect.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/container-instances/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Azure Pricing Calculator to figure out the cost

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/

[image]

Comment: on a 30 day month it comes to $41.40 USD, where as a Basic App Service Plan for Linux to host Web App Containers is $36.50 USD which has support for docker compose.

Comment: So the "seconds" is just time that the application is running whether or not it's actually consuming any CPU?
E.g., `while(true) { Console.Log("log"); Thread.Sleep(1000);}` would consume (about) one second, even though it's not doing anything for most of that time?